# I declared some other structure variables , those are working but this statement showing

Tags: c, c99

I created a structure, declare variable like
`struct Part R[size];` same like I declared some other structure variables, those are working
but this statement showing

```
error : expected ']' before ';' token
```

Comment: Tell us what compiler you are using. It looks like you may be trying to use a VLA (variable length array), but those are a C99 feature

Comment: You should post the actual code that you are using. It makes it easier for anyone viewing the question to provide helpful solutions.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the [help] on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests you missed inserting a `]` character before the `;` when you declare an array somewhere, such as in `int x[5;`

The compiler should inform you of the line number of the error.